# Why am I getting seemingly random syntax errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm trying to create a simple game known as Bulls and Cows on Visual Studio Code. The game is very incomplete as of now, but I keep compiling the program and it returns seemingly random errors that do not make any sense to me. Perhaps someone can explain why the compiler is returning these errors.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;


    class Game 
    {
        public:
            void StartGame();
        private:
            void EasyMode();
            void ModerateMode();
            void HardMode();
            string hidded_word;
            int bulls;
            int cows;
    };


    void Game::StartGame()
    {
        cout << "***********WELCOME TO BULLS AND COWS**************" << endl
        cout << "          Choose your difficulty" << endl << endl;
        cout << "    Easy       Moderate        Hard" << endl << endl;
        string difficulty;
        cin >> difficulty;
        cout << endl;

        if (difficulty == "Easy" || difficulty == "easy")
            {
                EasyMode();
            }
         else if(difficulty == "Moderate" || difficulty == "moderate")  
            {
                ModerateMode();
            }
          else(difficulty == "Hard" || difficulty == "hard")  
            {
                HardMode();
            }
    }


    void Game::EasyMode()
    {
     cout << "Easy mode";
    }

    int main()
    {
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "Hello Worldy";
    }
```

The compiler returns the errors below:

```
TestBullCow.cpp(38): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
TestBullCow.cpp(40): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
TestBullCow.cpp(40): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
TestBullCow.cpp(44): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
TestBullCow.cpp(44): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style 
 formal list?)
```

Comment: You have no `;` after `cout << "***********WELCOME TO BULLS AND COWS**************" << endl`

Comment: `else(difficulty == "Hard" || difficulty == "hard")  ` condition without `if` ?